# Trouble with dependent types in templates

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, stl

I'm having trouble with templates and dependent types:

```
namespace Utils
{
    void PrintLine(const string& line, int tabLevel = 0);
    string getTabs(int tabLevel);

    template<class result_t, class Predicate>
    set<result_t> findAll_if(typename set<result_t>::iterator begin, set<result_t>::iterator end, Predicate pred) // warning C4346
    {
        set<result_t> result;
        return findAll_if_rec(begin, end, pred, result);
    }
}

namespace detail
{
    template<class result_t, class Predicate>
    set<result_t> findAll_if_rec(set<result_t>::iterator begin, set<result_t>::iterator end, Predicate pred, set<result_t> result)
    {
        typename set<result_t>::iterator nextResultElem = find_if(begin, end, pred);
        if (nextResultElem == end)
        {
            return result;
        }
        result.add(*nextResultElem);

        return findAll_if_rec(++nextResultElem, end, pred, result);
    }
}
```

Compiler complaints, from the location noted above:

```
warning C4346: 'std::set<result_t>::iterator' : dependent name is not a type. prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'iterator'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In VS2017, this is now C7510.

Comment: And if you are using Re-sharper code issues, it will (probably) produce this warning: `Dependent type requires using 'typename' keyword`

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand why the original code is not here but the corrected code?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, the warning says:

> dependent name is not a type. prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type

The dependent name (that is, the `iterator` in `std::set<result_t>::iterator`) is not a type.  You need to prefix it with `typename` to indicate a type:

```
typename std::set<result_t>::iterator
```

So, your declaration should be:

```
template<class result_t, class Predicate>
set<result_t> findAll_if(typename set<result_t>::iterator begin, typename set<result_t>::iterator end, Predicate pred)
                                                note added typename ^
```

(and the definition should match the declaration)

Answer (score 9):

You need an additional typename keyword on this line:

`set<result_t> findAll_if(typename set<result_t>::iterator begin,`**typename**`set<result_t>::iterator end, Predicate pred) // warning C4346`