# How to initialize static field in template class with type of inner class

Tags: c++, templates, static-initialization

I have something like this

```
template <class T>
class Outer {
    public: class Inner;

    static Inner* x;

    //...

    class Inner {
        //...
    };
};

// Not working
template <class T>
Outer<T>::Inner* Outer<T>::x = NULL;
```

Error I get says: `:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token`

Comment: a `typename` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T>
class Outer {
public: 

    class Inner;

    static Inner* x;

    //...

    class Inner {
        //...
    };
};

template<class T>
typename Outer<T>::Inner *Outer<T>::x = NULL;
```

1. As for `typename` and `class`, please refer to [C++ difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)
2. Why this, please refer to [Trouble with dependent types in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931345/c-trouble-with-dependent-types-in-templates)